# MySQL: Cannot create user account after given root a password

Tags: mysql

I install the MySQL in my EC2 instance, then I give to root a password.

Now I'm trying to create an user to localhost domain and '%' domain too.
It was fine to create the user:

```
CREATE USER 'valter'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '******';
```

But when I try to grant it some privilegies :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'valter'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Gives me the follow error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) it says :

> shell> mysql --user=root mysql If you have assigned a password to the
>   root account, you will also need to supply a --password or -p option,
>   both for this mysql command and for those later in this section.

But how it should look like the command then ?

What I'm doing wrong here ?

I would like to create an user that have access to localhost and external network too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with EC2, not MySQL.  [Here's a relevant forum entry:](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=155742)

> The issue is that the RDS instance does not have superuser rights so I
>   can't "grant all privileges" to any user.
>
> I was able to get my application to work by creating the user with the
>   specific rights that I need (insert, update,create, etc)

This forum discussion may also be worth looking through:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64618

Comment: Is this correct? It seems like this answer is for Relational Datastore, but the question is about having installed MySQL on an EC2 instance.